# What is "bringing a pinwheel to a prizefight"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Whats the meaning of "bringing a pinwheel to a prizefight"

> I heard from legions of nervous Democratic strategists who worried that using “heal the nation” messaging against the MAGA meme army was like bringing a pinwheel to a prizefight.

https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/06/technology/joe-biden-internet-election.html

Comment: would you like to fight [this person](https://theweekendedition.com.au/events/prize-fighter/) using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinwheel_(toy)) as a weapon?

Comment: This is a variant (probably a newly-coined one) on [bringing a knife to a gun-fight](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bring_a_knife_to_a_gunfight).

Comment: *Heal the nation* doesn't have the same ring to it ;)

Comment: This sort of sophisticated metaphor won't show up in a dictionary, but pinwheels have a specific association with left-leaning politics and peace activism. They seem to have gotten attached to the *visualize whirled peas* meme. http://www.pinwheelsforpeace.com/Pinwheels_for_Peace/home.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's an established phrase, and I can't read the mind of the writer to know exactly what the pinwheel represents, but the general idea is clear: a pinwheel would be of little use in a fight, and may even get in the way. The writer also may have have intended a sense that the pinwheel's normal purpose is inappropriate: a pinwheel's purpose is to look pretty and make people feel good, but a prizefight is an adversarial event where the purpose is to beat the other person. Similarly, talking about healing the nation makes people feel good, but there's a worry that the campaign should be more adversarial.